# Regex: Copy a word/string below in a line above

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I want to copy a word/string below in a line above. For example I want to copy `TWO-2` from the second line into the first line, replacing the word `ONE-1`

```
BEBE ONE-1 NERO

text text

OANA TWO-2 BOGDAN
```

**MUST BECOME**

```
BEBE TWO-2 NERO

text text

OANA TWO-2 BOGDAN
```

**In other case, I have something like this:**

```
  html code ... several lines
  text <p> BEBE ONE-1 NERO <div> text...
    
  other  html code ... several lines
    
  text <table> OANA TWO-2 BOGDAN <tr> text
  again html code ... several lines
```

**MUST BECOME:**

```
  html code ... several lines
  text <p> BEBE TWO-2 NERO <div> text...
    
  other  html code ... several lines
    
  text <table> OANA TWO-2 BOGDAN <tr> text
  again html code ... several lines
```

My regex is very close to a simple solution, but I believe the replacement is not very good:

FIND (.matches newline): `(BEBE(.*?)NERO.*?)(OANA(.*?)BOGDAN)`

REPLACE BY: `\4\1\3\2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=BEBE ).+?(?= NERO.+?OANA (\S+) BOGDAN)`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=BEBE )          # positive lookbehind, make sure we have "BEBE " before (note the space)
.+?                 # 1 or more any character, not greedy
(?=                 # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
 NERO               # space, NERO
.+?                 # 1 or more any character, not greedy
OANA                # OANA, space
(\S+)               # group 1, 1 or more non spaces, you can use (.+?)
 BOGDAN             # space, BOGDAN
)
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1                  # content of group 1
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: thanks. Your regex is very good, thanks

Comment: How about vice-versa? If I want to change the word on top with the word on the second case? So as to copy `ONE-1` from first line to the second, as to become  `OANA ONE-1 BOGDAN` ? Can you update your answer with a regex formula for the second case?

Comment: @JustMe: Have a try with: Find: `BEBE (.+?) NERO.+?OANA \K\S+(?= BOGDAN)` Replace: `$1`. If it doesn't give the result you want, please, ask a new question with formated input string and expected result.

Comment: works @Toto, thanks a lot. Please update your answer with the second case. If I post a new question, it can be deleted, because is too similar